# How to numerate string after /n

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var MyString =  
"  
create xyz;  
create gfg;  
create xfa;  
create fgh; 
...
"
```

Can someone help me to achieve such a thing:

```
"  
1.  create xyz;  
2.  create gfg;  
3.  create xfa;  
4.  create fgh; 
...
"
```

What kind of method i should to use to achieve that in simplest way?
I think key char here is `;` because lines always end up with that char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match lines which end in `;`, and use a replacer function which prepends the line with a number that gets incremented:

```js
var MyString =  
`  
create xyz;  
create gfg;  
create xfa;  
create fgh; 
...
`;
let i = 1;
const replaced = MyString.replace(/.+;/g, line => `${i++}. ${line}`);
console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: unfortunately i have problem when i am trying to implement this into my code :< https://i.ibb.co/Sm5Fy5B/image.png  versions misses or something like that. Could you tell me how to write this in some other way?

Comment: you can use simple concat `.replace(/.+;/g, line => i++ + '. ' + line)`

Comment: Template literals are from ES2015, which was 5 years ago. If your IDE doesn't understand ES2015 (which was an eternity ago, in web development time), you should strongly consider getting a more modern IDE. (For a reasonably professional project of reasonable size, the best tried-and-true method is to write source code in the latest and greatest version of the language, then transpile down to ES5 or ES6 for production)

Comment: If that's not an option, you can use `+` to concatenate instead, but it's significantly less readable IMO

Comment: I can't change my version now :/ 
 Christian Carrillo your code is not working too. `expression expected`

Comment: nah i just changed that version, yolo